# awk command issue to recognize delimiter

Tags: linux, macos, awk

Experts, any thoughts why delimiter not working in my case? The '^A' is a real '^A' string, not ASCII value 1.

```
cat 2.txt
123^A9343784^A2207983400
45^A1270843^A66789439
67^A188285^A28075164
8^A91183^A27049564
9^A128589^A7283486
100^A84325^A7043462

cat 2.txt | awk -F'^A' '{print $1 }'
123^A9343784^A2207983400
45^A1270843^A66789439
67^A188285^A28075164
8^A91183^A27049564
9^A128589^A7283486
100^A84325^A7043462
```

BTW, working on Mac OSX/Linux.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

After some valid points made by *Ed Morton* in the comments area, I have updated my answer to provide slightly more insight on the different behavior of awk variants regarding escaping.

---

My understanding is that you want to use `^A` as delimiter.

You have to escape the `^` character, as it messes with awk's regex*.
The way to do this, is by prepending the double escape sequence `\\` to `^`

---

**-** In *Linux* (`awk` is usually [symlinked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) to `mawk` or `gawk`, see NOTE):

```
$ cat 2.txt | awk -F'\\^A' '{print $1 }' # mawk, gawk
```

Now, `mawk` has a slightly more relaxed behavior on this, so it is possible to achieve the same results using only `\` (single escape):

```
$ cat 2.txt | awk -F'\^A' '{print $1 }' # mawk (note the single backslash here)
```

however, in general,  this should be *avoided* (especially if used in a script or as a *passe partout* one-liner -portability comes to mind-), since other *awk* variants will treat this differently and a variety of unwanted outcomes will occur (some even well-disguised as legitimate ones in complex situations)

---

**-** In *Windows* (*cygwin*, *MinGW*, *gnutils* provide `gawk`):

```
$ cat 2.txt | awk -F'\\^A' '{print $1 }' # gawk
```

---

**-** In *OSX* (`awk` is by default `nawk`):

```
$ cat 2.txt | awk -F'\\^A' '{print $1 }' # nawk
```

All these yield:

```
123
45
67
8
9
100
```

*
*You can find more information on awk's Regular Expressions* [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html).

---

**NOTE**

In order to find which variant of `awk` is available in your system, first
you have to locate the awk command itself and then use `ls` to follow the link chain up to the actual binary, like this:

```
$ which awk
/usr/bin/awk
$ ls -l /usr/bin/awk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root ... /usr/bin/awk -> /etc/alternatives/awk
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/awk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root ... /etc/alternatives/awk -> /usr/bin/mawk
```

*(example taken from my system, Xubuntu 14.04)*

Comment: I tried on Mac OSX, I also need to use, \\ other than \?

cat 2.txt | awk -F'\\^A' '{print $1 }'
123
45
67
8
9
100

Comment: You mean that, in your OSX, the one that works is `-F'\\^A'`?

Comment: Thanks @sokin, question answered.

Comment: @lin-ma Glad it helped

Comment: Eveb if mawk can figure out what you meant when you wrote `\^A`, the correct syntax for mawk and all awks is `\\^A` because a field separator is a type of regexp and what you are assigning to it is a string and in all awks when a string is converted to a regexp one of the escapes chars is used up. Or to put it another way - any time you want to use a string in a regexp context and you need to escape a char in the regexp, you need to use double escapes because conversion of the string to a regexp uses up one escape and that just leaves the one you wanted for when the regexp is actually tested.

Comment: @ed-morton Yes, of course. You are right. Besides, this is why gawk issues a warning, when a single backslash is used as an escape for a char, stating that only the char (as-is, not escaped) will be taken into account for the regex. I will update my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Right - if you use one escape you're inviting nasal demons because some awks will treat that as none, some will treat it as 2, some will warn you and tell you what they're doing, and some will quietly do whatever they choose to do whether you wanted that or not.